# Cómo crear una lista pero con objetos de diferente clase Java

Tags: java

¿Cómo se puede crear una lista con diferentes tipos de datos?

la finalidad de eso es englobardatos en un encabezado

```
encabezado 1
dato 1
dato 2
dato 3
encabezado 2
dato 4
....
```

No ser si tengo que crear una clase abstracta que tanto el encabezado como los datos se extendan de ello, o bien hay alguna forma de meter en una lista diferente tipo de datos.

Clase Header

- Title

Clase Item

- Key
- value

Luego en recorrer la lista con ˋinstanceofˋ se detecta el tipo de uno o del otro?

Comment: Una opción es que header tenga una lista de items, con lo que tendrías una lista de headers que se depliega

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con Genericos.

```
class Header<T>{
    private T title;
    private List<Item> item;

    public T getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(T title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<Item> getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Item> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

}
class Item<K,V>{
    private K key;
    private V value;

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}

void load() {
    List<Header> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Item> listItem = new ArrayList<>();
    Header<String> headers = new Header<>();
    Item<Integer,String> item;
    //ejemplo
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        item = new Item<>();
        item.setKey(i);
        item.setValue("subMenu "+i);
        listItem.add(item);
    }        
    headers.setTitle("Menu1");
    headers.setItem(listItem);
    list.add(headers);
}
```

Te comparto un link para leer mas sobre genéricos 
[Genericos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear tus clases **Header** e **Item** con sus respectivos atributos y guardar todos los datos en una lista de tipo Object. Luego podrás identificar a cada uno con instanceof.
Por ejemplo:

```
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Header header = new Header(title);
    Item item = new Intem(key, value);
    list.add(header);
    list.add(item);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if(list.get(i) instanceof Header)
            System.out.println("Es un header");
        else if(list.get(i) instanceof Item)
            System.out.println("Es un item");
    }
```